# How to use Axios interceptors with useSWR to revalidate access/refresh JWTs? #2206

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios, vercel, swr

I was thinking about switching to SWR in my Nextjs project, but I stumbled upon an issue with the authentication of my app. It uses JWT authentication where the refresh token is stored as a httpOnly cookie on the client, and the access token is stored in memory on the client.

When a request to an endpoint which requires authentication returns a 403 status, a response interceptor that has been applied to the axios instance attempts to refresh the users tokens using the refresh token. It also applies a new header to the request to imply it has already been sent, as to prevent an infinite loop if the server again returns a 403 status. If the server returns with the new access token, then we append that to the Authorization header on the original request and retry it.

Now my question is how would you go about implementing this using SWR? Could you use the onErrorRetry option to achieve the same thing? Middlewares?

I have done my fair share of googling but I have yet to find a discussion on it, so I appreciate any input!

Comment: I had same worry. I chose react-query but swr.
They are have parameter fetcher function, so put here to call axios